# ntp 4.2.8p10 - disable signal I/O from configure script

Tags: ntp, qnx

I ran into a problem when cross-compiling NTP for QNX. I traced it down to a deadlock. Essentially what happens is:

```
t0 - clock_select() calls realloc()
t1 - realloc() locks the heap
t2 - signal handler is called
t3 - inside sig handler recvmsg() is called
t4 - recvmsg() calls malloc()
t5 - malloc() tries to lock the heap
DEADLOCK
```

I wondered why Linux does not run into this deadlock and it turns out that recvmsg() is considered [signal handler safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) while in QNX recvmsg() is explicitly listed as [not signal handler safe](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/r/recvmsg.html).

**MY QUESTION:** Is there a way I can pass an option to the configure script to manually disable signaled I/O when building NTP? I am really not wanting to manually edit source code so as to make it easier to upgrade to future versions of NTP. If there is no other way, which #defines should I disable in the resulting config.h script to not use signaled I/O?

I'm hoping to find a way to contribute to the NTP repo to add support for QNX, but for now these guys are hard to get a hold of.

Thank you all for your help and support!

Answer (score 0):

We've worked around this issue by turning off signaled i/o in ntpd by feeding
the following config.cache values to the configure script.

```
ntp_cv_hdr_def_sigio=${ntp_cv_hdr_def_sigio=no} 
ntp_cv_hdr_def_sigpoll=${ntp_cv_hdr_def_sigpoll=no}
```